# How to make eclipse not collapse subfolders?

Tags: eclipse, subdirectory

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Whenever I collapse a project or a folder in the Package Explorer and then reopen it I see Eclipse has collapsed all it's subfolders. This is very uncomfortable since I have to switch between projects a lot and reopening all the subfolders every time is annoying.

This wasn't the case with older Eclipse - Mars.2 Release (4.5.2). I could collapse a project, then return to it and see all the subfolders in open/closed state as it was before collapsing. And when I needed to collapse everything I just used the small "-" button in the Package Explorer menu.

Is there a way to return this behaviour?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in the current version of Eclipse (Photon). Are special/virtual/linked folders involved?

Comment: Nope. Maybe they fixed it.. Will have to upgrade then

Comment: I've updated to Photon and unfortunately it didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Since Eclipse uses native widgets, this could be OS-dependent. In which operating system and version (if Linux, also which GTK version) do you run Eclipse? Do you have additional plug-ins installed?

Comment: I'm on debian 9 with gnome 3.22.3, I have libgtk 2.24.31 and 3.22.11 installed and I'm using PyDev 6.5.0 in Eclipse.
Complete list of plugins here: http://joxi.ru/BA0OOwahJ9KXV2?d=1

Comment: Please check if this is a GTK 3.x issue: before starting Eclipse from the command line do `export SWT_GTK3=0`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't change it